# AngularJS SlimFramework

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, mongodb, slim

I have it code PHP with Slim Framework, it connect on mongoDb e find many data.

```
    <?php

use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface;
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface;

require 'vendor/autoload.php';
require 'config/config.php';
require 'conexao.php';

$app=new Slim\App(["settings" => $config]);
$app->get("/produto", function( $response,$request){
    $connection = connect();

    $produtos = array();
    $collection = $connection->lojavirtual->produtos;
    $result = $collection->find();
    $index = 0;

    foreach ($result as $produto){
        $produtos[$index]['nome']        = $produto['nome'];
        $produtos[$index]['categoria']   = $produto['categoria'];
        $produtos[$index]['valor']       = $produto['valor'];
        $produtos[$index]['avaliacao']   = $produto['avaliacao'];

        $index++;
    }

    echo json_encode($produtos);        
    });

    $app->post("/produto",function($request,$response){
        $connection = connect();

        $collection = $connection->lojavirtual->produtos;

        $result = json_decode($request->getBody(),true);

        $result = $collection->insertOne{['nome' => $result['produto']['nome'],
                                        'categoria'=>$result['produto']['categoria'],
                                        'valor' => $result['produto']['valor'],
                                        'avaliacao'>=0]};

        });

        $app->run();
?>
```

I can see the data from mongodb in this image.

[Data found in mongodb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpMAq.png)

In code below (index.html), i need show data from index.php, send by JSON,  but i can´t show them

```js
<html>
 <head>
 <title> Loja </title>
 <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.0/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script>
  var app = angular.module("lojaApp",[]);
  
  app.controller("produtosController",function($scope,$http){
   $scope.produtos;
   
   function atualizarLista(){
    $http({
     method:'GET',
     url:'/slim/produto'
    }).then(function(response){
       //Sucesso
       $scope.produtos=response.data;
    }, function (response){
     //erro
     alert(response.status);
    });
   }
   atualizarLista();
   $scope.categorias = ['Notebooks','SmartPhones','Livros'];
   $scope.salvarProduto = function(produto){
   $http({
    method:'POST',
    url:'/slim/produto',
    data:{'produto':produto)
   }).then(function(response){
    //sucesso
    atualizarLista();
   },function(response){
    //falha
    alert("Erro");
   });
   
   delete $scope.produto;
   }
   });
  </script>
 </head>

<body ng-app="lojaApp" ng-controller="produtosController">
 <h1 class="titulo"> Produtos Disponíveis</h1>
 <div id="listaProdutos" ng-repeat="produto in produtos">
  <div class="dadosProduto">
   <h4>{{produto.nome}} </h4>
   <p>{{produto.categoria}} </p>
   <p>{{produto.valor}} </p>
   <p>Avaliação : {{produto.avaliacao}} </p>
  </div>
 </div>  
 
 <div id="cadastroProduto">
     <h1 class "titulo"> Cadastrar Novo Produto </h1>
  <form name="formProduto">
   <input class="campo" type="text" placeholder="Nome do produto" ng-model="produto.nome"/>
   <input class="campo" type="text" placeholder="Valor do produto" ng-model="produto.valor"/>
   <select class="campo" ng-options="c for c in categorias" ng-model="produto.categoria"/> </select>
   <button ng-click="salvarProduto(produto)"> Salvar </button>
  </form>
 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.1/angular.min.js"></script>
```

But in my index.html, i can´t show data, css, fields and others..

Can anyone help me ?